# You don't have permission to access / on this server

Tags: wamp

I'm using Wamp server 2.2 on Windows 7. It was working well but after installing adobe photoshop software I'm facing some problem with wamp server. When I click on localhost it shows `Error 403 Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server`.
Please tell me what to do? How i can solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

LMAO, you probably have installed a cracked version of photoshop and followed the instructions of the crack.
Shame on you!
I'll help you, though.
Go to:
 `"c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\"` folder open the `"host"` file with an editor(notepad) and make sure that this is included and not commented out:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same situation one time and racked my brain for hours trying everything until I noticed the directory root files were all in color "red". If that is your case, select highlight all the files and folders that are in "red" right click and select "properties ". Select "Advance" untick the box that says "Files are encrypted". Click "Apply". Presto...it now works! :)